# Augmented matrix with symbolic variables and rref

Tags: matlab

Take a look at

```
syms x y z
A=[1 -2 x;2 1 y;-3 1 z]
rref(A)
```

This is an augmented matrix and I need the final output to be

```
1  0  | (x+2y)/5
0  1  | (y-2x)/5
0  0  | z+x+y
```

But `rref()` yeilds this

```
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

Any suggestions how to get the intended output?

Comment: Not an answer to your question as such, but you can extract the coefficients of interest from the result of `rref([A, eye(3)])`

Comment: @BenGrossmann this is close enough but not exactly. I've tried `simplify` but still I need to work it out to reach to my goal. thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the symbolic variables are confined to the right half of your augmented matrix, you could proceed as follows. Suppose that [A|B] is your augmented matrix. Then, you could do the following.

```
M = rref([A, eye(size(A,1))]);
C = M(:,(size(A,2)+1):end) * B;
```

In this case, C is the result of applying the row operations that brought M to its RREF to the symbolic matrix B.

---

Here's a modification that produces the result you initially expected.

```
syms x y z
A=[1 -2;2 1;-3 1];
B=[x;y;z];

[m,n] = size(A);
M = [eye(m),zeros(m,n)];
M(:,1:n) = A;
M(:,(m+1):end) = eye(m,n);
P = M(:,n+1:end);

R = rref(M);
C = R(:,n+1:end)/P*B;

disp(C)
```

Result:

```
 x/5 + (2*y)/5
 y/5 - (2*x)/5
     x + y + z
```